# How do get rid of (1 not defined because of singularities) in R?

Tags: multicollinearity, fixed-effects-model, categorical-encoding, linear-programming

I'm analyzing data in R, I'm trying to see how some variables affect test scores (Value) of different countries. In the data, since there is different time periods for different countries I need to use a panel technique to regress this data. I'm using a fixed-effect model, more specifically a constant-free model, where you include dummy variables for every particular country. In the equation I took off the intercept to eliminate collinearity. When I ran the regression, I could see the statistical information for all variables except one. I get "NA" for this variable in R. I think my model still suffers from collinearity and I think the solution to fix this problem is just to drop one dummy variable from the equation. I did do that and I'm no longer getting "(1 not defined because of singularities)". I just wanted to double check with someone else if I did the right thing? This is my code:

```
library(stats)
library(lmtest)
library(dplyr)
library(plm)

# running fixed effects with country dummies

Data_we_using2$LOCATION = as.factor(Data_we_using2$LOCATION)

dummyregress = lm(Value ~ Boysdummy + RGDPCapita+Graduation_rates + MissingGraDummy + Mortality_rate + GovtExpen + MissingGovt + Private + LOCATION-1, data = Data_we_using2)

summary(dummyregress)
```

LOCATION is the dummy variables of the countries. The pictures I included is the output I got for R. [image][image][image]

Comment: If you put a dummy variable in for every country, the dummy variables cause problems they are mutually dependent (each one is $1$ minus the sum of the others).

Comment: Technically, if you include `LOCATION - 1`, then all country-specific coefficients should appear in your summary output. It appears there is collinearity, but it's hard to diagnose without seeing your data. I would look at the model matrix and assess for any redundancies.

Comment: I used command "alias" in R and I think it tells you if there collinearity in the variables. I think in the Private dummy there is collinearity but dropping one country dummy variable seems to fix the problem.

Comment: @OmarPerezRodriguez This is a quick trick, but try specifying the country dummies first in terms of variable ordering. Does R drop `Private` or possibly any other variables?

Comment: @ThomasBilach I put the country dummy variables first in the equation and then I ran the regression. This time, the Private variable has "NA" on its statistical information. What does that mean?

Comment: One country effect is completely collinear with the `Private` dummy variable. In general, R uses variable ordering to break collinearity. If the country effects are specified first, then R will estimate all country-specific intercepts, but now it must drop `Private` as it is redundant with the dummy variable for the United States. I can't comment on why this is happening, but including a full set of country effects completely absorbs `Private`. I would start by investigating how `Private` is coded within each country.

Comment: @ThomasBilach We know now that the Private dummy is collinear with another dummy  variable but how do I fix that problem?

Comment: In practice, simply drop the variable. Note, R self-corrects by removing any redundant regressors. You may not have a problem at all. Is it safe to say that `Private` doesn't vary over time, particularly within the United States?

Comment: @ThomasBilach I have the Private dummy to represent the presence of private schools in different countries. The Private dummy shows the effect of private schools in test scores. I can not drop the Private dummy because it is a very important variable in my analysis. At least in the data I have, countries' test scores for different years, the Private dummy does not vary. Would it a good idea to just drop the USA dummy variable?

Comment: So the `Private` dummy is either all 0’s or all 1’s within a country, correct?

Comment: Yes the Private dummy is all 0s and 1s.

Comment: And is it like that *within* countries? In other words, the dummy doesn’t change over the time periods in any one country?

Comment: The Private dummy does not change over the time periods

Comment: Then the presence or absence of private schools is a fixed characteristic of each jurisdiction. A country either has private schools/universities or they don't. The country fixed effects already account for the time-constant attributes specific to your countries. This is why `Private` was dropped from your model. Does that make sense?

Comment: Your saying fixed-effect models account for time-constant attributes?

Comment: Precisely. The country fixed effects account for all *time-invariant* attributes specific to your countries.

Comment: @ThomasBilach ok, thank you. I'll just drop the Private dummy since fixed-effects is already adjusting for it.